# LUKS encrypted drive won't open even after passing valid passphrase

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, encryption, luks

I created a linux persistence LUKS encrypted drive /dev/sdb3 and I didn't access the drive for about 2 months since the thumbdrive was lost but after finding it when I select kali linux encrypted persistence and it asks for my passphrase and I enter the correct passphrase it doesn't work even when I boot into kali live and try opening the drive by double clicking and entering the password it hangs and the whole system becomes unresponsive what should I do to recover my data or gain access to the drive I really need the data

When I try with UFS Explorer here is the error that I'm getting
[image]

Comment: restore from backup

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Try decrypting it from command line (using command `cryptsetup open /dev/sdb3 disk`). Does that work ? If it doesn’t, I fear your data is lost unless you have a backup of the luks header

Comment: @Nephanth I've tried that but the command never returns a result it makes the entire system unresponsive I have to restart the system each time I try to decrypt the drive

Comment: I’d say your header is probably corrupted… maybe ddrescue the drive first, and try on that? but honestly, I wouldn’t raise my hopes up

Comment: @Nephanth I've tried ddrescue the process starts and after like 5 seconds and after creating a log file and an img file it never goes beyond that

Comment: wait you mean ddrescue stops in the middle of running? What makes you think it isn’t just running normally?